# how to slide menu with PC and phone?

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation menu with all categories 
 on PC it worked well with horizontal scrollbar, but on smartphones, I had to hide the scrollbar with CSS 
 this caused that on PC now they cannot slide categories
how can I make it work on both?

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 45px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl00_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=19">cat 1</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl01_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=22">cat 2</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl02_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=17">cat 3</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl03_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=9">cat 23</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl04_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=12">cat 5</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl05_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=7">FARINA DA GRANI ANTICHI</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl06_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=13">FRUTTA</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl07_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=15">FUNGHI NATURALI</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td>
            &nbsp;
            <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DataList1_ctl08_hypCateg" href="Index.aspx?CodCateg=16">MAIALE</a> &nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to hide scrollbar in mobile Please check https://jsfiddle.net/hardik_g_/bukh1nc9/2/
simple added  `.child::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 0px;height:0px;background: transparent;} .child::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: transparent;}`

Comment: yes, like this it works in mobile, but on PC the scroll does not appear, i want both